# Problems connecting Qlistwidget itemDoubleClicked signal with a slot

Tags: qt, signals, slots

I am having problems conecting the itemDoubleClicked() signal with a slot in my qt program. I think that it should be working but something goes wrong. I define the GUI by Qt code. Here is the connection part of the code.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QListWidget *mImagesListWidget = new QListWidget();   
 connect(mImagesListWidget,SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(on_imageListItem_DoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));
}

void MainWindow::on_imageListItem_DoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem listItem){
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText(listItem.text());
            msgBox.exec();
}
```

I don't know what could be the problem. Any help or sugestion is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your parameters.

Emitting:

> itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*) <-- pointer

Slot:

> on_imageListItem_DoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem listItem) <-- value

connect returns a bool. Always good to check it to see if a connection was made.

Comment: Nice! I did not know that the connect() method returns a bool. Thanks for that trick